# Which IIR form has lowest round-off noise?

Tags: noise, infinite-impulse-response

We are making some audio effects using IIR, and seeking ways to optimize its round-off noise. After searched some materials, most of them tells **transposed form II** has lowest round-off noise, and many IIR libraries are implemented in it. However, some other materials tells **direct form I** is the best. So which one should I choose?

Here are specifications of our working signal and currently applied strategy:

- direct form I;
- sample rate in 48000 or 44100 Hz;
- input/output data in single-precision float, inner state storage and calculation in double-precision;
- running in CPU.

At current, this strategy hears good. But we are still seeking on reduce double-precision calculation to single precision, if possible.

Comment: Roundoff noise depends on filter structure AND on filter coefficients, so no one-size-fits-all strategy. Analytic noise estimation for floating point IIR is a PITA. I recommend simulating both and measuring distortion, noise.